# How to track exact event handler of HTML element, if it is not registered with the element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using some third party control in my aspx form. The control renders into the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" style="height: 20px; text-align: right;" class="edit" id="numberBox" />
```

Now at the time I press any key in this input text field, event fires but those events are not registered here with element perhaps the events are registered by the control somewhere else in the JavaScript files that are registered along with this control.

My question is how to track that exact event handler, is there any tool for it to see all the associated events of that particular element.

Comment: What language and platform are you using? What kind of control?

Comment: Do not flag your question for moderator attention because you could not find an acceptable answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this
`alert(document.getElementById("numberBox").onkeypress)`. See if you can see the source code of the onkeypress event. If it is null, it means no event is registered to the onkeypress event.

You can write a for in loop to show all the members (including the event) of an object with javascript.

Comment: The above code returns null on both keypress and keydown events although the input field doesn't allow entering any special characters that means some event is firing which is causing special characters not to be entered in the input text element.

Is there any other way to track the listener event handler?

Comment: May be the event handler is register on one of parent elements. You know if the 3rd party library uses any other javascript library?

Comment: I try to register the event with jQuery just now and the onkeypress is undefined, but the event work. If I register the event myself with DOM level 0 (i.e. assign the handler directly to onkeypress). It will return the source code. I suspect that the event is registered by attachEvent(IE) / addEventListener(W3C). May be you try to override the event to see if you can work out if it is in the input or somewhere else.